# How to make the Resource/NotResource field case insensitive in AWS s3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage, netapp

I have set below bucket policy to whitelist around 100 file types in s3 bucket:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1610615475618",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1610615465140",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<acc_name>:user/<user_name>"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "NotResource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*.PNG",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*.JPG",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*.txt",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*.mp3",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*.Docx"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

But the issue here is if I write png instead of PNG, the PNG file uploads starts failing. And the same happens with other file type also. I have 100+ file type and its very difficult to test each and every file type. So is there any way to make the NotResource field case insensitive.

Comment: A user could upload an image without a filename extension and it would work perfectly well as an image, and people could upload a non-image with a filename extension that matches an image. Thus, it isn't a particularly secure way to "protect" content. What is your actual intention? (That is, _what_ are you trying to accomplish, rather than _how_ you are wanting to do it?)

Comment: My requirement is to allow only certain file types in my bucket. I agree that user can change the file extension and upload. But is there any other way to restrict file types which is not required in my application, like .exe, .bat, .jar, .sh etc . I want to secure my bucket.

Comment: Amazon S3 only serves static content, so it cannot be made less secure by storing executable files, but those files could certainly be a security threat if users were to download and execute them. You could use `Content-Type` metadata associated with objects, but they can be faked or left blank. Aside from actually scanning the contents of a file, I can't think of a way that you could guarantee the type of files that are uploaded.